# Generate text adversarial example

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def fgsm_attack(model, x, epsilon):
    x = tf.Variable(x, dtype=tf.float32)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(x)
        logits = model(x, training=False)
        loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)(tf.ones_like(logits), logits)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, x)
    perturbation = epsilon * tf.sign(gradients)
    perturbed_x = tf.clip_by_value(x + perturbation, 0, 1)

    return perturbed_x

imdb = tf.keras.datasets.imdb
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)

x_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=256)
x_test = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=256)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 16),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

# Choose a test sample for adversarial attack
index = 0
test_sample = x_test[index]
true_label = y_test[index]


epsilon = 0.1
perturbed_sample = fgsm_attack(model, test_sample[np.newaxis, :], epsilon)


original_pred = model.predict(test_sample[np.newaxis, :])
perturbed_pred = model.predict(perturbed_sample)

print("Original Prediction:", original_pred)
print("Perturbed Prediction:", perturbed_pred)
print("True Label:", true_label)
```

this is actually a Fast gradient sign method on textual adversarial attack which is applied on IMDB review dataset and it gives the below error so if anyone can fix it it will be helpful.Please guys is there anyone to help respond please if you know about this .
In this example, we first load the IMDB Movie Review dataset and preprocess the data by padding the sequences to a fixed length. We then define a simple text classification model using an embedding layer, global average pooling, and dense layers. After compiling the model, we train it on the dataset.

To perform the FGSM adversarial attack, we define the fgsm_attack function. This function takes the trained model, an input sample x, and an epsilon value as parameters. It computes the gradients of the loss function with respect to the input, generates a perturbation based on the sign of the gradients, and applies the perturbation to the input. The resulting perturbed sample is returned.

Finally, we choose a test sample from the IMDB dataset, generate the adversarial example using the FGSM attack, and evaluate the model's predictions on the original and perturbed samples.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-ede1bb26e4c3> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 epsilon=0.1
----> 2 perturbed_sample = fgsm_attack(model,test_sample[np.newaxis, :],epsilon)
      3 # Evaluate the model on the original and adversarial examples
      4 original_pred = model.predict(test_sample[np.newaxis, :])
      5 perturbed_pred = model.predict(perturbed_sample)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    101       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    102   ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 103   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    104 
    105 

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```